# Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 software RAID10 (4*4TB) boot issues

Tags: boot, server, grub2, partitioning, raid

I'm struggling with getting my Ubuntu server up and running. I have four 4TB drives and want to set up a software RAID10.

All drives are set to GPT and I booted the setup via a USB flash drive in UEFI mode.

I've partitioned all four drives equally as follows:

- 4GB "physical volume for RAID"
- ~4TB "physical volume for RAID"

Then I've set up RAID10 over the four partitions with no spare drives. The resulting partitions were configured as follows:

- 8GB SWAP
- 8TB EXT4 / (root partition)

Ubuntu server happily installed, but failed to boot.

So I repeated the setup, but added a 1MB partition, set as `Reserved BIOS boot area` on the first drive and 1MB partitions, which should not be used on the rest of the drives.

Grub failed to install.

So I repeated the setup and created four 1MB `physical volume for RAID`s, created a RAID10 with the four partitions and on the resulting 2MB partition configured the `Reserved BIOS boot area`.

Grub failed to install again.

How do I get a software RAID10 with four 4TB drives to boot Ubuntu Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this seems to work:

- Booted USB flash drive in UEFI mode.
- 1MB `Reserved BIOS boot area` on each disk.
- The rest on each disk as `physical volume for RAID`, which is then configured as RAID10.
- The resulting 8TB partition was configured as an `LVM volume group`, with two `logical volumes`. One for SWAP the other as root.
- Install GRUB to the MBR

Tested and working with Ubuntu server 16.04.1 and 14.04.4

Comment: Similar challenge/solution, but here: a) 8TB drives b) No UEFI (2012 BIOS) c) skipped LVM d) Ubuntu 16.04.4. Mainly: thanks for mentioning `Reserved BIOS boot area` without which my install could not grub!